# Cannot return a collection data in mongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to return a collection data in mongoDB shell.
These are the commands I have entered in the MongoDB shell:

```
> **show dbs**
local     0.000GB
messages  0.000GB
restapi   0.000GB
> **use restapi**
switched to db restapi
> **show collections**
messages
> **restapi.messages.find()**
```

The error:

> 2017-02-26T19:03:50.024+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError:
>   restapi is not defined :`

To show that I do have records in the messages collection, I am attaching a  screenshot:

[image: RoboMongo screenshot]

Why can't I view the collection contents?

Comment: Try `db.messages.find()` is the mongo shell syntax similar to what you have for robomongo. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: thank you! I though `db` means the db name!

Answer (score 2):

db is a keyword, not the db name.
Try db.messages.find()
If you want proper JSON, try db.messages.find().pretty()